# FacebookDesktop.fqlQuery does not work when trying to retrieve users photos

Tags: apache-flex, air, facebook-graph-api

When attempting use the the Adobe GraphAPIDesktop library for use with Adobe Flex and AIR I can login to Facebook and retireve wall posts etc ok using FQL or Graph API calls.  When attempting to retrieve users photos I can only get tagged photos when using "me/photos".  I am trying to use FQL whcih should work, but when using:

var query:String = "SELECT pid, aid, owner, src, src_big, src_small, link, caption, created, modified FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( '1622751608028', '1207785754141' ) ";

FacebookDesktop.fqlQuery(query, getPhotos2);

Only an empty OBject is returned from FB?

Hope someone can help

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I realised I needed to include the session id in this fql as I was using JSON loader's in the last version of my app.  The fql situated above was within a JSON loader having already sent the session id to FB.